# Micro-optimizations: if($var){ ... } vs if($var): ... endif

Tags: php, performance, conditional-statements, micro-optimization

Is `if($var){ ... }` faster than `if($var):  ... endif` ?

Which one do you use?

Comment: Quoting myself from another one of your questions: "Forget about micro-optimizations. Focus on writing clean, easy-to-read code."

Comment: If you become so desperate to squeeze out performance that this becomes an issue, you shouldn't be using PHP.

Comment: Really. Who keeps upvoting these stupid questions?

Comment: why is it stupid? I think it makes sense..

Comment: I recommend `if () { }` inside large blocks of PHP and `<?php if () : ?> <?php endif; ?>` inside HTML blocks, for **readability**. I *do not* differentiate them on speed, because there's probably no difference.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it a "stupid question".  If he doesn't know, he needs to.  That isn't to say that there aren't plenty of stupid questions out there ;)

Comment: Obviously, because you didn't spend much thought on this or read the replies on your last questions. To answer it: same bytecode. Negligible difference for the tokenizer and parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure the difference is negligible, if there is any.  If the difference *is* important to you, you should probably use a faster (likely compiled) language.

You would do better optimizing more intensive things, like databases first (and writing clean code, as @Tim stated).

Answer (score 0):

I think both are the same. Personally I prefer `if($var: ... endif;`. php is a template language and that syntax leads to extremely well toward it. I actually put all variables in `<? ... ?>` tags to keep it all clean and concise.